# ROS installation on intel edison

Tags: intel, ros, intel-edison

I am getting following error while installing ROS on intel edison with UbiLinux. Following these steps for installation http://wiki.ros.org/wiki/edison

```
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:380:43: error: macro "BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp: In member function ‘ros::CallbackQueue::CallOneResult ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*)’:
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_`enter code here`comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:380:7: error: ‘BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT’ was not declared in this scope
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:381:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:384:7: error: ‘struct boost::scope_exit::aux::undeclared’ has no member named ‘value’
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:384:7: error: ‘boost_se_guard_384’ was not declared in this scope
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:398:9: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp: At global scope:
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:408:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:413:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:416:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@ubilinux:/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roscpp#
```

Comment: Obviously boost version mismatch. Expected newer/older but got older/newer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove libboost-all-dev 1.4.9, then compile and install boost 1.5.3.

Follow these instructions:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

http://yplam.com/ros/2017/03/19/edison-ros-install.html

Comment: It would be better if the answer would describe how this is done, or summarize the external links.